# Wildfly / Infinispan HTTP session replication hits ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling CGLIB Session Bean

Tags: spring, spring-security, wildfly, infinispan

I'm running **Wildfly 20.0.1.Final** in `standalone`, two-node cluster. I'm trying to implement HTTP Session sharing between the nodes.

In my Spring web application I have `<distributable/>` in my `web.xml`.

My session object is this:

```java
package my.package;

@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class MySessionBean implements Serializable {
  // omitted for brevity
}
```

As you can see, I have `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`.

When I perform a failover in Wildfly, my HTTP Session can't be restored however, as I hit this warning:

```
2021-02-22 13:24:18,651 WARN  [org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan] (default task-1) WFLYCLWEBINF0007: 
Failed to activate attributes of session Pd9oI0OBiZSC9we0uXsZdBwkLnadO1l4TUfvoJZf: 
org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi.InvalidSerializedFormException: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MySessionBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c0fa1df 
from [Module "deployment.myDeployment.war" from Service Module Loader]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MySessionBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c0fa1df from [Module "deployment.myDeployment.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.9.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.ModularClassResolver.resolveClass(ModularClassResolver.java:133)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.9.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1033)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.9.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1366)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.9.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:283)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.9.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:216)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.9.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi.util.MapExternalizer.readObject(MapExternalizer.java:65)
...
```

Note, that the `ClassNotFoundException` is complaining because the lack of `my.package.MySessionBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c0fa1df`, which is the Spring-enhanced bean of my `MySessionBean` bean.

Changing to `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` is not an option.

Can you please point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: 9 out of 10 reasons you get a `ClassNotFoundException` is due to incompatible dependency versions. So i would start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by creating a simple POJO, called `MySessionDTO`, and using that in my session.

So initially I had this (which threw the exception in the question):

```java
request.getSession().setAttribute("mySession", mySessionBean);
```

...and after I created `MySessionDTO` (see below), I refactored it into this:

```java
request.getSession().setAttribute("mySession", mySessionBean.getMySessionDTO());
```

`MySessionDTO` is a simple POJO:

```java
package my.package;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MySessionDTO extends MySessionBean implements Serializable {
  public MySessionDTO (MySessionBean mySessionBean) {
    this.setAttributeX(mySessionBean.getAttributeX());
    this.setAttributeY(mySessionBean.getAttributeY());
  }
}
```